# How to process Matlab Audio Format?

Tags: matlab, audio, signal-processing

I have downloaded a EEG recording of a person in Matlab-Audio Format. I have no idea of how to use it in Matlab for further processing. Is it possible to generate signals in Matlab? If so, is there any code to generate EEG signal?

Comment: What is the extention of the file?

Comment: '.m' format... @shkrishtensen

Answer (score 2):

Some versions of Winamp and Microsoft Access set the description for the .mat file extension to "MATLAB Audio Format", although I have *no idea* what this means.  It's unclear to me if such a unique file type really exists; I'd love to know more if there is actually some special format of which I am not aware.  More likely, the file you downloaded is simply a standard [MATLAB .mat file](http://www.mathworks.com/help/pdf_doc/matlab/matfile_format.pdf) containing the EEG data in one or more variables.  You can read the variables in MATLAB with the [`load`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/load.html) command.  To see the variable names contained in the MAT file prior to loading it, use [`whos`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/whos.html) with the `-file` switch.